# MATLAB Plot vertical line

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I have a system of equations, about 3 equations, that I need to plot that are dependent on 2 variables, R and z. But one of the equations is `R={constant value}`. Here's the code:

```
R = 0:.1:500;
z = 5./R;
z2 = 40./R;
z3 = 20
plot(R, z, R, z2, R, y3)
```

...I don't really know how to get `z3` to show up as a vertical line. Any ideas?

Comment: y3 is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z3` not showing up is because it has different size with `R`. In `plot` command two vectors must share the same length.

A simple solution is:

```
R = 0.1:.1:500;
z = 5./R;
z2 = 40./R;
z3 = 20;
plot(R, z, R, z2)
hold on;
plot([z3 z3], [min([z(:);z2(:)]) max([z(:);z2(:)])]);
```

[image: graph]

Notice here `0` is excluded for otherwise `max` will give an `Inf`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent answer over on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108766/1194420 repeated below for convenience. (Please go there an up vote the original answer) ---

There exist an undocumented function graph2d.constantline:

```
plot(-2:5, (-2:5).^2-1)
%# vertical line
hx = graph2d.constantline(0, 'LineStyle',':', 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hx,'x');
%# horizontal line
hy = graph2d.constantline(0, 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hy,'y');
```